# Problem when using dotnet-clear tool with framework dotnet core 3.1

Tags: c#, compatibility, .net-core-3.1, dotnet-tool

I am currently developing code using the dotnet core 3.1 framework on a new pc.
I installed the latest version of the dotnet-clear tool using this code:

> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-clear

When I use it, the following output is displayed.

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.1.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.1.2 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.1.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

The **Microsoft.NETCore.App** framework is installed during dotnet core installation.
From the message it would seem that I need to install dotnet core 2.1 but I was using dotnet core 3.1 and dotnet clear on the old pc.

Any idea how to solve the situation?

Comment: Do you mean dotnet clean? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-clean

Comment: No, I mean exactly dotnet-clear tool [https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-clear/](https://www.nuget.org/packages/dotnet-clear/)

Comment: Have you installed a dotnet core 2.1 sdk? Because that tool is not compatbile with 3.1 and you do not say you have installed it (in addition to 3.1). Happens when tools are not supported (that has last update 2018).

Comment: Does that other machine by any chance have both frameworks?

Comment: @TomTom you're right. I thought I had uninstalled dotnet core 2.1 and instead checked the sdk on the known system that is still present.